# accessing currentCSSState property on event.target.incrementButton

Tags: apache-flex

I am currently creating a spinner like this

```
                    var scoreSpinner:Spinner = new Spinner();
                scoreSpinner.width = 25;
                scoreSpinner.value = scoreList.getItemAt(index).Score;
                scoreSpinner.minimum = scoreList.getItemAt(index).Minimum;
                scoreSpinner.maximum = scoreList.getItemAt(index).Maximum;
                scoreSpinner.snapInterval = 1;//scoreList.getItemAt(index).Increment;

                if(scoreNameLabel.text == "Disconnect Impact")
                {
                    scoreSpinner.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, spinnerChange);
                }
```

On a specific spinner I want to do custom incrementing (0, 1, 3, 5, 7) so I want to know when they push increment button to know which way to increment the value

```
            private function spinnerChange(event:Event):void
        {
             if(event.target.incrementButton.currentCSSState.valueOf() == "down")
            {
                if(event.currentTarget.value == 2)
                    event.currentTarget.value = 3;

                if(event.currentTarget.value == 4)
                    event.currentTarget.value = 5;

                if(event.currentTarget.value == 6)
                    event.currentTarget.value = 7;
            }

            if(event.target.incrementButton.currentCSSState.valueOf() == "up")
            {
                if(event.currentTarget.value == 2)
                    event.currentTarget.value = 1;

                if(event.currentTarget.value == 4)
                    event.currentTarget.value = 3;

                if(event.currentTarget.value == 6)
                    event.currentTarget.value = 5;
            } 

        }
```

I get this error when it runs

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property currentCSSState not found on spark.components.Button and there is no default value.
at lcmp.web.wsc.ui.shared.controls.PreWSC.ProgramScore::ProgramScore/spinnerChange()[C:\TFS\Release Branches\CR13\Flex\Web\WSC\src\lcmp\web\wsc\ui\shared\controls\PreWSC\ProgramScore\ProgramScore.mxml:298]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()
at spark.components::Spinner/decrementButton_buttonDownHandler()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Spinner.as:455]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()
at spark.components.supportClasses::ButtonBase/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\ButtonBase.as:745]
at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()
```

anyone know how I can use this property or just a better way of doing this with a spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such property named "currentCSSState". However, the `Spinner` control has a `stepSize` property you can use which controls how much the spinner is incremented/decremented when you click the button. If you set the `stepSize` to 2, this seems close to what you're looking for.

If you want to have more control of how the spinner increments/decrements the value, you can override the `Spinner` control's methods `incrementButton_buttonDownHandler()` and `decrementButton_buttonDownHandler()`, which are executed when you click the buttons.

Here is the default implementation of one of these methods:

```
protected function incrementButton_buttonDownHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var prevValue:Number = this.value;
    changeValueByStep(true);
    if (value != prevValue)
        dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
}
```

You can  override this to increment `this.value` to your liking rather than calling the `changeValueByStep()` method. You might want to take a look at that `changeValueByStep()` method so you can see what it is doing (it honors the min/max values, lets the value wrap to the beginning if you reach the end, etc.).