# Flex spark spinner, swap arrows behavior

Tags: apache-flex

Is there a simple way to swap the incremental and decremental buttons behaviors?
so the up arrow decreases the value and the down arrow increases it.

Comment: Have a look at the answer I gave for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975457/accessing-currentcssstate-property-on-event-target-incrementbutton/13976741#13976741). You can extend the Spinner control to do this. The question I link to is different than what you're asking, but the answer should help you. Another approach would possibly be to make your own skin for the Spinner. Feel free to up vote that answer if you find it helpful :)

Comment: I was going to suggest creating your own skin; and switching the names of the down arrow and up arrow buttons.

Comment: The custom skin solution seems the easiest and most transparent to me.

Comment: @ www.Flextras.com lol!, that was so simple, saved me from hard-coding the spinner, thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This skin, for the spark spinner component, solves the problem . I inverted the skin class property and the top down attribute value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" alpha.disabled="0.5" minHeight="23" minWidth="12">

    <fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[ 
        /** 
         * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
         */
        [HostComponent("spark.components.Spinner")]
    ]]>
    </fx:Metadata> 

    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
        /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. 
           For spinner, the skin itself is colorized but the individual parts are not. */
        static private const exclusions:Array = [ "incrementButton","decrementButton",];

        /**
         * @private
         */   
        override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return exclusions;}

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override protected function initializationComplete():void
        {
            useChromeColor = true;
            super.initializationComplete();
        }

        private var cornerRadiusChanged:Boolean;

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        override protected function commitProperties():void
        {
            super.commitProperties();

            if (cornerRadiusChanged)
            {
                var cr:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius");
                if (incrementButton)
                    incrementButton.setStyle("cornerRadius", cr);
                if (decrementButton)
                    decrementButton.setStyle("cornerRadius", cr);
            }
        }

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        override public function styleChanged(styleProp:String):void
        {
            var allStyles:Boolean = !styleProp || styleProp == "styleName";

            super.styleChanged(styleProp);

            if (allStyles || styleProp == "cornerRadius")
            {
                cornerRadiusChanged = true;
                invalidateProperties();
            }
        }
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
    </s:states>



    <!--- decrement button with increment skin -->
    <s:Button id="decrementButton" left="0" right="0" top="0" height="50%" tabEnabled="false"  
              skinClass="spark.skins.spark.SpinnerIncrementButtonSkin" />

     <!--- increment button with decrement skin -->
    <s:Button id="incrementButton" left="0" right="0" bottom="0" height="50%" tabEnabled="false" 
              skinClass="spark.skins.spark.SpinnerDecrementButtonSkin" /> 



</s:SparkSkin>
```